# How to force GHC to inline FFI calls?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ffi

I made small C module to improve performance, but GHC doesn't inline foreign functions, and calls cost eliminates the acceleration.
For example, `test.h`:

```
int inc (int x);
```

`test.c`:

```
#include "test.h"
int inc(int x) {return x + 1;}
```

`Test.hc`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Test (inc) where
import Foreign
import Foreign.C
foreign import ccall unsafe "test.h inc" c_inc :: CInt -> CInt
inc = fromIntegral . c_inc . fromIntegral
{-# INLINE c_inc #-}
{-# INLINE inc #-}
```

`Main.hs`:

```
import System.Environment
import Test
main = do {args <- getArgs; putStrLn . show . inc . read . head $ args }
```

Making:

```
$ gcc -O2 -c test.c
$ ghc -O3 test.o Test.hs
$ ghc --make -O3 test.o Main
$ objdump -d Main > Main.as
```

Finally, in `Main.as` I have `callq  <inc>` instructions instead of desirable `inc`'s.

Comment: You expect ghc to inline a C function in its generated code?  This might work if you use the -via-C option, otherwise it's hopeless (since it would require ghc to read the C code and generate code for it).

Comment: Not possible in absence of link-time optimisation. One (hacky) approach to try is to compile both Haskell and C to LLVM bitcode, combine the .bc files with `llvm-link`, optimise with `opt` and then emit executable code with `llc`.

Comment: @MikhailGlushenkov, could you write a sketch of making commands sequence? I failed to google out how to obtain `.bc` files from haskell code.

Comment: Provide a type for `inc`. Currently you're converting it to an Integer, is that what you intend? That's going to swamp the FFI overehad (around 900ns per call, IIRC)

Comment: @leventov `-keep-llvm-files` gives you `.ll` assembly which you can then compile with `llvm-as`.

Answer (score 9):

GHC won't inline C code via its asm backend or LLVM backend. Typically you're only going to call into C for performance reasons if the thing you are calling really costs a lot. Incrementing an int isn't such a thing, as we already have primops for that.

Now, if you call via C you may get GCC to inline things (check the generated assembly).

Now, however, there's some things you can do already to minimize the call cost:

```
foreign import ccall unsafe "test.h inc" c_inc :: CInt -> CInt

inc = fromIntegral . c_inc . fromIntegral
```

Provide a type signature for `inc`. You're paying precious cycles converting to Integer here.

Mark the call as "unsafe", as you do, so that the runtime is not bookmarked prior to the call.

Measure the FFI call overhead - it should be in the nanoseconds. However, if you find it still too expensive, you can [write a new primop and jump to it directly.](http://breaks.for.alienz.org/blog/2012/05/23/ffi-vs-primops) But you better have your [criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion) numbers first.

Comment: Actually my "inc" is the set of branchless SSE min-max functions: https://gist.github.com/4476908

Comment: Ah I see -- you really do want new primops then. You're duplicating some thing of http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3557 ?

Comment: Generally no, but maybe these min-max instructions are particularly considered in the ticket, I haven't studied it in details.