# Squeezing more performance out of monadic streams in Haskell

Tags: performance, haskell, stream, monads, ffi

The most straightforward monadic 'stream' is just a list of monadic actions `Monad m => [m a]`. The [`sequence :: [m a] -> m [a]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:sequence) function evaluates each monadic action and collects the results. As it turns out, `sequence` is not very efficient, though, because it operates on lists, and the monad is an obstacle to achieving fusion in anything but the simplest cases.

**The question is: What is the most efficient approach for monadic streams?**

To investigate this, I provide a toy problem along with a few attempts to improve performance. The source code can be found on [github](https://github.com/mcmayer/haskell-lfsr). The singular benchmark presented below may be misleading for more realistic problems, although I think it is a worst-case scenario of sorts, i.e. the most possible overhead per useful computation.

**The toy problem**

is a maximum length 16-bit [**L**inear **F**eedback **S**hift **R**egister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register) (LFSR), implemented in C in a somewhat over-elaborate way, with a Haskell wrapper in the `IO` monad. 'Over-elaborate' refers to the unnecessary use of a `struct` and its `malloc` - the purpose of this complication is to make it more similar to realistic situations where all you have is a Haskell wrapper around a FFI to a C `struct` with OO-ish `new`, `set`, `get`, `operate` semantics (i.e. very much the imperative style). A typical Haskell program looks like this:

```
import LFSR

main = do
    lfsr <- newLFSR            -- make a LFSR object
    setLFSR lfsr 42            -- initialise it with 42 
    stepLFSR lfsr              -- do one update
    getLFSR lfsr >>= print     -- extract the new value and print
```

The default task is to calculate the average of the values (doubles) of 10'000'000 iterations of the LFSR. This task could be part of a suite of tests to analyse the 'randomness` of this stream of 16-bit integers.

**0. Baseline**

The baseline is the C implementation of the average over `n` iterations:

```
double avg(state_t* s, int n) {
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++, sum += step_get_lfsr(s));
    return sum / (double)n;
}
```

The C implementation isn't meant to be particularly good, or fast. It just provides a meaningful computation.

**1. Haskell lists**

Compared to the C baseline, on this task Haskell lists are 73x slower.

```
=== RunAvg =========
Baseline: 1.874e-2
IO:       1.382488
factor:   73.77203842049093
```

This is the implementation ([`RunAvg.hs`](https://github.com/mcmayer/haskell-lfsr/blob/master/RunAvg.hs)):

```
step1 :: LFSR -> IO Word32
step1 lfsr = stepLFSR lfsr >> getLFSR lfsr

avg :: LFSR -> Int -> IO Double
avg lfsr n = mean <$> replicateM n (step1 lfsr) where
    mean :: [Word32] -> Double
    mean vs = (sum $ fromIntegral <$> vs) / (fromIntegral n)
```

**2. Using the [`streaming`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming) library**

This gets us to within 9x of the baseline,

```
=== RunAvgStreaming ===
Baseline: 1.9391e-2
IO:       0.168126
factor:   8.670310969006241
```

(Note that the benchmarks are rather inaccurate at these short execution times.)

This is the implementation ([`RunAvgStreaming.hs`](https://github.com/mcmayer/haskell-lfsr/blob/master/RunAvgStreaming.hs)):

```
import qualified Streaming.Prelude as S
avg :: LFSR -> Int -> IO Double
avg lfsr n = do
    let stream = S.replicateM n (fromIntegral <$> step1 lfsr :: IO Double)
    (mySum :> _) <- S.sum stream
    return (mySum / fromIntegral n)
```

**3. Using [`Data.Vector.Fusion.Stream.Monadic`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector-Fusion-Stream-Monadic.html)**

This gives the best performance so far, within 3x of baseline,

```
=== RunVector =========
Baseline: 1.9986e-2
IO:       4.9146e-2
factor:   2.4590213149204443
```

As usual, here is the implementation ([`RunAvgVector.hs`](https://github.com/mcmayer/haskell-lfsr/blob/master/RunAvgVector.hs)):

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Fusion.Stream.Monadic as V
avg :: LFSR -> Int -> IO Double
avg lfsr n = do
   let stream = V.replicateM n (step1' lfsr)
   V.foldl (+) 0.0 stream
```

I didn't expect to find a good monadic stream implementation under `Data.Vector`. Other than providing `fromVector` and `concatVectors`, `Data.Vector.Fusion.Stream.Monadic` has very little to do with `Vector` from `Data.Vector`.

A look at the profiling report shows that `Data.Vector.Fusion.Stream.Monadic` has a considerable space leak, but that doesn't sound right.

**4. Lists aren't necessarily slow**

For very simple operations lists aren't terrible at all:

```
=== RunRepeat =======
Baseline: 1.8078e-2
IO:       3.6253e-2
factor:   2.0053656377917912
```

Here, the for loop is done in Haskell instead of pushing it down to C ([`RunRepeat.hs`](https://github.com/mcmayer/haskell-lfsr/blob/master/RunRepeat.hs)):

```
do
   setLFSR lfsr 42
   replicateM_ nIter (stepLFSR lfsr)
   getLFSR lfsr
```

This is just a repetition of calls to `stepLFSR` without passing the result back to the Haskell layer. It gives an indication of what impact the overhead for calling the wrapper and the FFI has.

**Analysis**

The `repeat` example above shows that most, but not all (?), of the performance penalty comes from overhead of calling the wrapper and/or the FFI. But I'm not sure where to look for tweaks, now. Maybe this is just as good as it gets with regards to monadic streams, and in fact this is all about trimming down the FFI, now...

**Sidenotes**

1. The fact that LFSRs are chosen as a toy problem does not imply that Haskell isn't able to do these efficiently - see the SO question ["Efficient bit-fiddling in a LFSR implementation
   "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43601927/efficient-bit-fiddling-in-a-lfsr-implementation).
2. Iterating a 16-bit LFSR 10M times is a rather silly thing to do. It will take *at most* 2^16-1 iterations to reach the starting state again. In a maximum length LFSR it will take *exactly* 2^16-1 iterations.

**Update 1**

An attempt to remove the `withForeignPtr` calls can be made by introducing a
`Storable` and then using `alloca :: Storable a => (Ptr a -> IO b) -> IO b`

```
repeatSteps :: Word32 -> Int -> IO Word32
repeatSteps start n = alloca rep where
    rep :: Ptr LFSRStruct' -> IO Word32
    rep p = do
        setLFSR2 p start
        (sequence_ . (replicate n)) (stepLFSR2 p)
        getLFSR2 p
```

where `LFSRStruct'` is

```
data LFSRStruct' = LFSRStruct' CUInt
```

and the wrapper is

```
foreign import ccall unsafe "lfsr.h set_lfsr"
    setLFSR2 :: Ptr LFSRStruct' -> Word32 -> IO ()

-- likewise for setLFSR2, stepLFSR2, ...
```

See [RunRepeatAlloca.hs](https://github.com/mcmayer/haskell-lfsr/blob/master/RunRepeatAlloca.hs) and [src/LFSR.hs](https://github.com/mcmayer/haskell-lfsr/blob/master/src/LFSR.hs). Performance-wise this makes no difference (within timing variance).

```
=== RunRepeatAlloca =======
Baseline: 0.19811199999999998
IO:       0.33433
factor:   1.6875807623970283
```

Comment: I'd try to localize the slow part down at the FFI level. E.g. let the FFI-called function be ultimatey trivial, returning 0. Does calling it still cost a lot? How much repackaging the arguments cost? Etc.

Comment: you mean calling only `void f(...)` functions? I.e. repackaging the getters?

Comment: Yes. Maybe it's the access to the arguments, or packaging the return value, what is killing the performance; for a `void nothing() {}` it might be visible. OTOH calling an external procedure just for a side effect (not passing or receiving data) would make little sense even if stream fusion is achieved, so my point may be moot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deciphering GHC's assembly product for `RunRepeat.hs` I'm coming to this conclusion: GHC won't inline the call to the C function `step_lfsr(state_t*)`, whereas the C compiler will, and this makes all the difference **for this toy problem**.

I can demonstrate this by forbidding inlining with the `__attribute__ ((noinline))` pragma. Overall, the C executable gets slower, hence the gap between Haskell and C closes.

Here are the results:

```
=== RunRepeat =======
#iter:    100000000
Baseline: 0.334414
IO:       0.325433
factor:   0.9731440669349967
=== RunRepeatAlloca =======
#iter:    100000000
Baseline: 0.330629
IO:       0.333735
factor:   1.0093942152684732
=== RunRepeatLoop =====
#iter:    100000000
Baseline: 0.33195399999999997
IO:       0.33791
factor:   1.0179422450098508
```

I.e. there is no penalty for FFI calls to `lfsr_step` anymore.

```
=== RunAvg =========
#iter:    10000000
Baseline: 3.4072e-2
IO:       1.3602589999999999
factor:   39.92307466541442
=== RunAvgStreaming ===
#iter:    50000000
Baseline: 0.191264
IO:       0.666438
factor:   3.484388070938598
```

Good old lists don't fuse, hence the huge performance hit, and the `streaming` library also isn't optimal. But `Data.Vector.Fusion.Stream.Monadic` gets within 20% of the C performance:

```
=== RunVector =========
#iter:    200000000
Baseline: 0.705265
IO:       0.843916
factor:   1.196594188000255
```

It has been observed already that GHC doesn't inline FFI calls: ["How to force GHC to inline FFI calls?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14199402/how-to-force-ghc-to-inline-ffi-calls)
.

For situations where the benefit of inlining is so high, i.e. the workload per FFI call is so low, it might be worth looking into [`inline-c`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/inline-c).